# How to deploy antd-admin dashboard in apache2?

Tags: apache2, antd

I am deploying ant-admin dashboard in apache2 rather nginx.
How do I configure apache2 for antd-admin dashboard?
repo: https://github.com/zuiidea/antd-admin

```
npm run build
// Generated build files under /dist
```

copy paste in apache2 document root /Library/Web

```
cp -r /dist Library/WebServer/Documents/
```

trying to call
http://localhost/dist

Page is not loading
When I checked console. css, js files are serving from http://localhost/umi.css but expecting it should serve from http://localhost/dist/umi.css

How do I serve css, js and sub directory /dist in apache2?

Comment: I would be better if you'd describe the actual approach you've taken in this post yourself, instead of providing a link were it is described. Would you mind updating the post accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

use home page key in the package.json

"homepage": "./dist"

https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/deployment#step-1-add-homepage-to-packagejson